# How to make TextField text on the same line as prefixIcon?

Tags: flutter

I want my TextField input to be on the same line as the prefix icon.
I tried many things including contentPadding but nothing worked.

[image]

I want the text to be in the middle of the shopping cart icon.
contentPadding just moves the whole thing instead of just text

```
        child: TextField(
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            labelText: 'name of grocery item',
            labelStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
            border: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
            ),
            // contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left:10),
            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5, left: 25),
            prefix: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 12.0),
              child: Icon(Icons.local_grocery_store),
            ),
            focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
              borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.green),
            )
          ),
        ),
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use the `prefixIcon` constructor in `Textfield` widget to achieve this as follows

```
TextField(
          decoration: InputDecoration(
              labelText: 'name of grocery item',
              labelStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
              border: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
              ),
              // contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left:10),
              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 0, left: 25),
             
                prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.local_grocery_store),),
             
              focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.green),
              )),
        ),
```

[image: result]

Comment: Now works beautifully. I don't know I missed the prefixIcon parameter. Thanks man

Answer (score 0):

Remove conten padding top - 5 or put contentpadding.all(5)